# How to re-open modal window after ModalState is invalid with the errors shown?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a login modal window which has validation. The problem is that I can not re-open the modal window when the validation fails.

So, I have this controller: `Index()` which returns the `View` of the homepage. On that homepage, I have the modal window which has the validation.
But after clicking the submit button (`Login()` controller), and after validation failure, the URL is /Index/Login and I can not pass `ViewBag` value which tells the modal to re-open.

Here is the code from both controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View();
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Users user)
{
 if (ModelState.IsValidField("username") && ModelState.IsValidField("password"))
    {
      if (Users.Login(user))
          {       
           //some custom logic
           return RedirectToAction("../Dashboard/Dashboard");
          }
          else
          {
              ViewBag.LoginError = "Wrong username/password";
          }       
      }
      else
      {

      }
      return View("Index");
  }
```

I really need help guys. I am trying to solve this the whole day!

PS: I work with Razor syntax on the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the section scripts in your _Layout.cshtml which is in the /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml then paste the below code at the end of the /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>

        @if(ViewBag.LoginError == "Wrong username/password")
        {
            WriteLiteral("$('#login-modal').modal('show');");
        }
    </script>
}
```

This can be done ajax way too however above is the solution to your question.

If the section scripts is not defined in _Layout.cshtml, then define this section at the end of the _Layout.cshtml just like below.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```